# read data from json file and create html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Hello I am new  for jquery and json file,I want to create html file from json file.first data read from .json file then on the basis of json object create html file   my json data  is :--

```
   {"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"5544F75A-4589-4605-B447-0AB123A1865D","parent_guid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","ElementName":"Main","elementtype":"Form","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"0","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"width":"28%","height":"200px"}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"6EB6C873-E2EC-4515-A6D8-2FBF0119F573","parent_guid":"5544F75A-4589-4605-B447-0AB123A1865D","ElementName":"MainTab","elementtype":"tab","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"0","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"width":"65%"}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"6E13FCBC-0DB2-4499-B200-61CD5A36F0C1","parent_guid":"6EB6C873-E2EC-4515-A6D8-2FBF0119F573","ElementName":"Results","elementtype":"tabdetail","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"2","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"E5539403-9A58-4310-8013-AF4EEF62C217","parent_guid":"6EB6C873-E2EC-4515-A6D8-2FBF0119F573","ElementName":"Billing","elementtype":"tabdetail","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"1","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"113293EE-0997-4398-8E4A-6BE7AEDC32C1","parent_guid":"6EB6C873-E2EC-4515-A6D8-2FBF0119F573","ElementName":"Utilities","elementtype":"tabdetail","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"3","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"4EFA32EC-B37E-4DC2-A249-E7156196918F","parent_guid":"6E13FCBC-0DB2-4499-B200-61CD5A36F0C1","ElementName":"ResultsTab","elementtype":"tab","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"0","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"F6FB6DAA-F6D9-43B0-88FD-688BEC0EAF32","parent_guid":"E5539403-9A58-4310-8013-AF4EEF62C217","ElementName":"BillingTabHeader","elementtype":"tab","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"1","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"9E622E70-095A-4A1A-BA06-C67946D49549","parent_guid":"F6FB6DAA-F6D9-43B0-88FD-688BEC0EAF32","ElementName":"Current Billing","elementtype":"","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"3","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"B41D9F7B-ED6F-47C5-8562-437D9F5F23AD","parent_guid":"F6FB6DAA-F6D9-43B0-88FD-688BEC0EAF32","ElementName":"Billing","elementtype":"","elementsource":"Sp_getBilling","onload":"","sequence":"1","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"151F6F13-C200-4EDA-8467-1D5AEB5F03A2","parent_guid":"F6FB6DAA-F6D9-43B0-88FD-688BEC0EAF32","ElementName":"PreBilling","elementtype":"","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"2","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}},{"userguid":"AB92DE99-D0D5-4081-802C-2E331F88AE84","sessguid":"AEA0774B-8CCE-4CB1-A6F8-484ADA1FB45F","transguid":"","ret_code":"ok","ret_mess":"","rec_guid":"91158CB4-C93B-4440-BAA4-771E9493EEA9","parent_guid":"F6FB6DAA-F6D9-43B0-88FD-688BEC0EAF32","ElementName":"Final Billing","elementtype":"","elementsource":"","onload":"","sequence":"4","isPublic":"0","attributes":{"":""}}
```

I tried this but this is not  :-

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div style="margin: 20px auto; width: 500px;">
  <form border="1" cellpadding="5" id="jsonTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
 </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
  var columnSet = [];
  var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');
  for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  var rowHash = myList[i];
  for (var key in rowHash) {
  if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
    columnSet.push(key);
     headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
   }
  }
  }
 $("#jsonTable").append(headerTr$);
 return columnSet;
 }

 $.getJSON("demo.json", function (data) {
 var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(data);
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row$ = $('<tr/>');
  for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
   var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];
     if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
     row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
    }
    $("#jsonTable").append(row$);
   }
 });
```

I want to create html according to element type in JSON array. if like element type is form then html create form  and if element type is tab then create tab.

Comment: nice, but in this website people help to solve your problem on existing code, not to code from scratch. Read a tutorial on js and html

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
if (data[i].elementtype === "Form" {
        //build form here
    }
    if (data[i].elementtype === "tab" {
            var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(data);
            //etc
        }
}
```